# Alternate background color for ListView class even without data

Tags: android, listview

I want to set an alternating color for my custom `ListView` class.

The code is given below:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

   public class CustomListView extends ListView {
    private Paint   mPaint              = new Paint();
    private Paint   mPaintBackground    = new Paint();

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#1A000000"));

    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        final int currentHeight = getMeasuredHeight();

        final View lastChild = getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
        if (lastChild == null)
            return;
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (getChildCount() % 2 == 0) {
                mPaintBackground.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            } else {
                mPaintBackground.setColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }

        final int lastChildBottom = lastChild.getBottom();

        final int lastChildHeight = lastChild.getMeasuredHeight();

        final int nrOfLines = (currentHeight - lastChildBottom) / lastChildHeight;

        Rect r = new Rect(0, lastChildBottom, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
        canvas.drawRect(r, mPaintBackground);
        canvas.drawLine(0, lastChildBottom, getMeasuredWidth(), lastChildBottom, mPaint);
        for (int i = 0; i < nrOfLines; i++) {
            canvas.drawLine(0, lastChildBottom + (i + 1) * lastChildHeight, getMeasuredWidth(), lastChildBottom + (i + 1) * lastChildHeight, mPaint);
        }
        return;
    }
    }
```

To get an alternating background color for `ListView`, I have used this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
   if (getChildCount() % 2 == 0) {
      mPaintBackground.setColor(Color.WHITE);
   } else {
      mPaintBackground.setColor(Color.RED);
   }
}
```

Inside of the adapter:

```
    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
```

But it always shows one color, red or white with everything I try. I am not getting alternating colors white-red-white-red.

Comment: You are using wrong method to achieve your result. dispatchDraw method is only called once. you should use getView method for such behaviour which is called for every item. @faizan has suggested the right solution

Comment: Oh. Really ? So how it would be ?

Comment: see the complete comment.

Comment: @SAIR Have you checked my edited question. I have also posted my adapter code.!

Comment: The adapter code will only work when there *is* data. If you want to alternate colors for the entire ListView even if there isn't data, it will have to be done in dispatchDraw. I am trying to edit my answer now.

Comment: Yeah you'r right. I want that one !!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason this is failing is because your for loop never changes. You are always checking `getChildCount() % 2`. `getChildCount()` will return the same for each iteration. You need to do your check based on position:

```
for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++){
   if(i % 2 == 0){
      mPaintBackground.setcolor(Color.WHITE);
   } else{
      mPaintBackground.setColor(Color.RED);
   }
}
```

If it helps, rename your counter variable from `i` to `position` so that this will be more readable for you in the future, or make a note of it to help yourself out.

I would also like to add that, given the code you have now, your for loop isn't changing anything. It is just iterating through the number of children and setting `mPaintBackground`. In the end, it will be left with whatever value it receives from the last iteration.

I think the best way to handle drawing the background color would be in the adapter for the Listview, in which case you can override [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) and do a check based on the `position` parameter:

```
int backgroundResource;
if(position % 2 == 0){
   backgroundResource = getResources.getColor(android.R.color.WHITE);
} else{
   backgorundResource = getResources.getColor(android.R.color.RED);
}
view.setBackground(backgroundResource);
```

Of course, the above is just pseudocode, it may need to be adjusted to your project.

---

The above solution will work only for existing data. If you need an alternating color regardless of whether or not there is data, which if I understand now is what you were trying to achieve in `dispatchDraw`. I will be very honest that I am not 100% sure how to do this, and I cannot test it, but I imagine the steps going like this:

- Get the height of the ListView
- Get the width of the ListView
- Get the height of one child (listPreferredItemHeight, if you use that. If you use wrap content, this might be trickier because you cannot predict the size of the items, so alternating colors for an empty ListView would be difficult).
- While there is space left in the ListView, draw a rectangle.

Note here that you **cannot** iterate based on number of children, because you might not have any at this point.

Pseudocode:

```
listViewWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
listViewHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
numChildren = getChildCount();
itemHeight = getItemHeight(); // See comments above, adjust this for your problem.
currentTop = 0; // Used to keep track of the top of the rectangle we are drawing.
currentBottom = itemHeight; // Used to keep track of the bottom rectangle we are currently drawing.

int currentRectangle = 0;
while(currentBottom <= listViewHeight){
   if(currentRectangle  % 2 == 0){
      mPaintBackground.setColor(Color.WHITE);
   } else{
      mPaintBackground.setColor(Color.RED);
   }

   Rect r = new Rect(0, currentBottom, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
   canvas.drawRect(r, mPaintBackground);

   // Move to next
   currentTop += itemHeight;
   currentBottom += itemHeight;
   currentRectangle++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But if i use this then it shows only white color.

Comment: @PiyushGupta at which line are you painting the background? In the code you have, it looks like you go through and iterate `getChildCount()` but don't do anything but set the paint background color, which will be left at whatever value it's given on the last iteration. Perhaps when you call `getView()` in your adapter, you can do a check based on `position`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)

Comment: Yes i am checking it with position. But at-least if the data may be empty then listView will show as a with alternate white-red bg color. but it's not showing !

Comment: @PiyushGupta do you have an adapter class for your ListView? Can you share the adapter code as well?

Comment: @PiyushGupta so if the ListView is empty you still want to see alternating colors? Are the colors alternating when the ListView isn't empty?

Comment: Yes.. color is alternating when listView is not empty and yes you understand properly that if listView is empty i also need same alternate color !!

Comment: @PiyushGupta I understand. I will try to edit answer one more time.

Comment: @PiyushGupta I may be wrong, but I took a stab at it. I am not 100% if my code is right, but I hope it puts you on the right track.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your efforts. Let me check. I will back to you !!

Comment: @PiyushGupta I have to edit one more time I made a dumb mistake.

Comment: Oh My God. After using this i got weird result. Its alternating but much weird

Comment: @PiyushGupta well then we might be on the right track ;P

Comment: Yes. We are. Wanna see screenshot?

Comment: @PiyushGupta Sure. Let's move this discussion to [our own chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86605/discussion-between-piyush-gupta-and-mcadam331).

Comment: Hello Mate. Are you there ?

Comment: @PiyushGupta a little bit. What do you need?

Comment: The thing which we have implemented is working well. But the issue is for last row when i expand my layout on button click then that expandable layout takes a white background and grey background for that. !!

Comment: @PiyushGupta well you're doing onDraw() inside the ListView class, is the expandable layout also part of the ListView, or is it a different layout all together? Because that's what it sounds like to me.

Comment: Yes it is in custom layout file. Initially it is hidden but when click on button it will open with animation.(means expanding with animation)

Answer (score 11):

Finally I got my answer with the huge help of @McAdam331. After using his code i got some weird thing but after that i have repaired code using this one

```
        int listViewHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        int itemHeight = lastChild.getMeasuredHeight();
        int currentTop = 0;
        int currentBottom = lastChild.getBottom();

        int currentRectangle = 0;
        while (currentBottom <= listViewHeight) {
            if (currentRectangle % 2 == 0) {
                mPaintBackground.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            } else {
                mPaintBackground.setColor(Color.parseColor("#f7f7f7"));
            }

            Rect r = new Rect(0, currentBottom, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
            canvas.drawRect(r, mPaintBackground);

            // Move to next
            currentTop += itemHeight;
            currentBottom += itemHeight;
            currentRectangle++;
        }
```

Comment: Glad you got this working, I updated my answer to reflect the correct `Rect()` constructor.

Answer (score 3):

There is a small mistake in the logic.
here is the updated code for that section:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(getResources.getColor(Color.WHITE));
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(getResources.getColor(Color.RED));
        }
    }
```

The check should be on counter control variable, getChildCount will always return the total # of items that is why you always see same color.
The above pasted code will solve your problem. But this code should be in getView() for your adapter class, because getView() function is called on every row for rendering. 
Your current approach will just call the function once and you will not achieve the desired result.

Comment: I have updated the answer. This code snippet should be in the getView() of your adapter class. Your current code snippet is related to listview widget, but what exactly you want is the customization over the row of listview.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the same effect for a `Listview` by simply creating a custom `Adapter`:

```
public class MyAlternateColorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SomeObject> {

    private Context context; //Get the Context from the constructor

    ...

    @Override 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);

        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // Or use rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_red); where bg_red is a drawable with a selector to provide touch feedback
        } else {
            rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        // Set the data of the row
        ...
    }
}
```